# Complex query with filters with Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have the following tables (and relevant fields):

```
users           (id, name)
companies       (id, name)
sales           (id, company_id, user_id)
products        (id, description)
products_sales  (id, product_id, sale_id)
```

Now, I have some report generation with multiple concurrent filters:
company name, user name, product.

I want the Company to be the 'top level' object in the result.
So,

```
Company::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$company_name%")
```

then

```
  ->whereHas('sales', function ($query) use ($user_name) {
      $query->whereHas('user', function ($query2) use ($user_name) {
          $query2->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$user_name%")
      });
  });
```

This is complex enough already, and I also want to eager load all
relationships, to optimize database access, so I ended up with:

```
$cond = function($q) use ($user_name) {
    $cond2 = function ($q2) use ($user_name) {
        $q2->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$user_name%");
    };

    $q->whereHas('user', $cond2)
      ->with(['user' => $cond2]);
};
Company::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$company_name%")
    ->whereHas('sales', $cond)
    ->with(['sales' => $cond]);
```

I feel this brings unnecessary repetition. Moreover, when filtering
products the same way, I think the eager loading supersedes the previous one.

So... What's the better way to do this?
Can I use Eloquent for this or should I go back to a 'raw' query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect the queries that Eloquent generates by using [`getQueryLog`](http://www.goodbytes.be/blog/article/log-last-executed-eloquent-query-as-plain-sql-in-laravel-5).  If your query is looking "less than optimal", you might consider a raw query.

If your query is optimal but the Eloquent syntax looks too "messy", you might consider building some of the partial [query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes) into your models.

For example, you could define a scope in your `Sales` model to match names:

```
class Sales extends Model
{
    /**
     * Scope a query to only include Sales for users with a matching name.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeMatchUserName($query, $user_name)
    {
        $cond2 = function ($q2) use ($user_name) {
            $q2->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$user_name%");
        };

        return $query->with(['user' => $cond2])
                     ->whereHas('user', $cond2);
    }
}
```

Then your query becomes somewhat simpler (looking):

```
$cond = function($q) use ($user_name) {
    return $q->matchUserName($user_name);
};

Company::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$company_name%")
    ->with(['sales' => $cond])
    ->whereHas('sales', $cond);
```

You can even package *that* query into your `Company` model:

```
class Company extends Model
{
    /**
     * Scope a query to only include Companies and Sales for a matching user and company name.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeMatchCompanyAndUserName($query, $user_name, $company_name)
    {
        $cond = function($q) use ($user_name) {
            return $q->matchUserName($user_name);
        };

        return $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$company_name%")
            ->with(['sales' => $cond])
            ->whereHas('sales', $cond);
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do is:

```
Company::matchCompanyAndUserName($user_name, $company_name);
```

Comment: Thanks! +1 for the `getQueryLog` tip, and also for the scopes idea (might be a good place to encapsulate some filtering logic). However, the first thing about `whereHas` not being necessary when eager loading with `with` is not right I think. [Details in pastebin](http://pastebin.com/iyQBdq38)

Comment: Hmm so, `Sales` that don't have any matching users should be omitted from the results entirely?

Comment: Yes in this case, I just want to generate a report filtering sales per user.

Comment: Ok, in that case there might be another way that doesn't require you to run the filter twice.  Let me think about this.

Comment: what if you try [filtering](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-filter) the collection after you load it using `with`?  Then you can eliminate any `Sales` that have no matching users.  I believe this would save you an extra query due to the `whereHas` clause.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing it the old SQL way. I will consider your suggestion for next time, though.

Comment: Cool, don't forget to accept this answer!