# Eloquent eager loaded query not quite working with joins

Tags: php, join, eloquent

I'm working on a Chemical database and am learning Eloquent as I go.  This is in Slim Framework, not Laraval itself.
This thread helped get me close to what I need, but now I'm seeing something odd and I haven't been able to find a solution, though lots of people asking similar questions.

I have

```
$chemicals = $app->Chemical->with(array('Company', 'Room', 'Location', 'Measurement'))
->join('company', 'company_id', '=', 'company.id')
//->join('room', 'room_id', '=', 'room.id')
//->join('location', 'location_id', '=', "location.id")
->where('company', '=', 'ROUSSEL')
->get();
```

Notice the 2 Joins commented out. Those 2 fields do display properly in my table, but company is blank.  If I switch which join is shown, it follows suit.

If I don't use any of the joins, I can do a where just fine with one of the chemical fields. My question is why does having a join seem to break that particular With statement and is there a way to fix it?  I get the feeling that it's something to do with the With statement doing some kind of behind the scenes join, but I haven't been able to find any specifics..
Thanks,

Forgot to mention I had tried Eager Loading Constraints before as well.

```
$chemicals = $app->Chemical->with(
array(
    'Company', 
    'Room', 
    'Measurement',
    'Location' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('location', '=', 'FLAMCAB');
    }
))
//->where('company', '=', 'FISHER')
->get();
```

Using above without the where commented out gives me the message that the chemicals table does not have a column called company, which is true.
Not using it, I do get results:

[image: Table when using the eager loading constraint]

As you can see it does filter the locations table, but it does only that, it doesn't filter chemicals by that, which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Do you have to use `join`?  Have you looked into [Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) yet?

Comment: Hi @alexw, I thought I would have to for this particular query.  I am using relationships in that a Chemical belongsTo each of these 4 objects and in turn they hasOne Chemical. Is there something more in there that I could use to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Well what I'm saying is (and if I remember your schema from your last question), those `join` clauses seem unnecessary.  It looks to me like all they're doing is grabbing the associated company, room, and location for each of your chemicals.  But, if you have `belongsTo` relationships already defined, then the `with` clause should be sufficient to get the associated company, room, and location for each chemical.

Comment: It is sufficient until I need to filter by one of the related fields, like Location. 
Just realized that above when I said "This thread helped me" I forgot to include it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789285/eloquent-nested-relation-with-some-constraint
This explains it really well, but I've tried taking it one step further.

Comment: I'm not sure your situation is as complicated as the one presented in that thread.  Try my answer first to see if it gets you what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter Chemicals based on their related Locations, you can combine [constraining eager loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) with [querying relationship existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations):

```
$filter = function ($query) {
    $query->where('location', '=', 'FLAMCAB');
};

$chemicals = $app->Chemical->with(
    array(
        'Company', 
        'Room', 
        'Measurement',
        'Location' => $filter
    )
    ->whereHas('location', $filter)
    ->get();
```

I'm not sure how efficient this is though - you might want to check out the resulting query.  Another option is to simply filter the collection using [Collection filters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-filter) after you run the query.

This question: [Complex query with filters with Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132859/complex-query-with-filters-with-eloquent) might also help you.

Comment: This answer works.  Very cool.  I did look at the querylog and it doesn't look too bad.  Of course I only have a half dozen entries now but I'll have close to 2000 when all is said and done.  Once I get to that point, I'll do some more testing and if it's really slow, I'll keep in mind the filtering afterwards option.  In your experience, which do you think would be faster?
Thank you very much for your efforts

Comment: It's a tough call.  If Eloquent has to generate a whole extra query for the `whereHas`, then its going to have to walk your collection anyway to merge the results.  If you can walk the collection without needing another query, that will probably be faster.  The only way to be sure though, is to measure the time (for example, with [`microtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php))